# elasticSearch query by ancestors

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index with  documents like this:

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90323",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90323",
                    "code": "A01",
                    "code_raw": "A01",
                    "description": "Desc for A01",
                },
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90324",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90324",
                    "code": "A01.2",
                    "code_raw": "A012",
                    "description": "Desc for A01.2",
                },
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90325",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90325",
                    "code": "A01.3",
                    "code_raw": "A013",
                    "description": "Desc for A01.3",
                },
            },
            {
                "_index": "icd",
                "_type": "icd10",
                "_id": "90326",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90326",
                    "code": "A01.34",
                    "code_raw": "A0134",
                    "description": "Desc for A01.34",
                },
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90327",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90327",
                    "code": "A01.35",
                    "code_raw": "A0135",
                    "description": "Desc fro A01.35",
                },
                "sort": [
                    "Z1321"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90328",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90328",
                    "code": "A01.356",
                    "code_raw": "A01356",
                    "description": "Desc for A01.356",
                },
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "90329",
                "_source": {
                    "codeId": "90329",
                    "code": "A01.359",
                    "code_raw": "A01359",
                    "description": "Desc for A01.359",
                },
            },
...
]
```

I usually query the children with something similar to `GET http://[host:port]/myindex/mytype/_search` with a query:

```
"query":{
            "match_phrase_prefix":{
               "code_raw":"A01"
            }
         }
```

now I need the inverse task, for example for code_raw A01359, I need the documents A01359, A0135, A013 and A01, is there an easy way with elasticsearch?, or i just preprocess the code and query for each document individually?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is create a new analyzer. The analyzer uses the tokenizer edge_ngram.

But this analyzer will be applied only at search time, with the search_analyzer.

This allow create tokens like:

```
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": ["A01359"]
}
```

Token:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "a01",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "a013",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "a0135",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "a01359",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

With this, it will be possible to match the value in the code_raw field of other documents.

Full example:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
            ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "code_raw": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"standard", 
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A01"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A012"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A013"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A0134"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A0135"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A01356"}
{"index":{}}
{"code_raw": "A01359"}
```

Query

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "code_raw": {
        "query": "A01359"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "Jy7yz4UBKJKciEqCsxO7",
    "_score": 1.6739764,
    "_source": {
      "code_raw": "A01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "KS7yz4UBKJKciEqCsxO7",
    "_score": 1.6739764,
    "_source": {
      "code_raw": "A013"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "Ky7yz4UBKJKciEqCsxO7",
    "_score": 1.6739764,
    "_source": {
      "code_raw": "A0135"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "LS7yz4UBKJKciEqCsxO7",
    "_score": 1.6739764,
    "_source": {
      "code_raw": "A01359"
    }
  }
]
```